# files.equal not returning true

Tags: java, file

Basically, I have two Strings that are Fully Qualified File Names.  I want to compare that the two files are the same thing.  So I converted both Strings to File Objects.  Using google's Files.equal(File file, File file2) method, I tried to compare them, but the value returned was false.  However, wondering what was wrong, I converted both file objects to byte arrays and output those which equaled the same number.  So, does anyone know why Files.equal is considering them false.

I'm just curious why the method is returning false because after reading the doc Files.equal compares the two files by bytes.

Thanks.

Code:

```
    public class WhenEncrypting {

private String[] args = new String[4];

/**
 * encrypts a plain text file
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 *             IOException could occur
 */
@Test()
public void normalEncryption() throws IOException {
    this.args[0] = "-e";
    this.args[1] = "./src/decoderwheel/tests/valid.map";
    this.args[2] = "./src/decoderwheel/tests/input.txt";
    this.args[3] = "./src/decoderwheel/tests/crypt.txt";

    DecoderWheel.main(this.args);

    File plainFile = new File("./src/decoderwheel/tests/input.txt");
    File crypted = new File("./src/decoderwheel/tests/crypt.txt");

    byte[] f1 = Files.toByteArray(plainFile);
    byte[] f2 = Files.toByteArray(crypted);
    int number = f1.length;
    int size = f2.length;
    Files.equal(crypted, plainFile);
    System.out.println(number);
    System.out.println(size);
    System.out.println(Files.equal(crypted, plainFile));

    assertTrue(Files.equal(crypted, plainFile));

}

}

 Output:
 360
 360
 false
```

Comment: Show your code. In particular this part: "*I converted both Strings to File Objects*"

Comment: And also: *converted both file objects to byte arrays*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930859/java-file-equals

Comment: @ZongZhengLi - not helpful.  The OP is not asking how to compare files (or filenames).  He's asking why a **specific way of doing it** is apparently not working.

Comment: It's a JUnit test by the way

Comment: @Dan - you are not going to get a good answer unless you show us the relevant code.  The fact that it is a JUnit test is unlikely to make any difference.

Comment: Maybe the 2 files aren't the same.

Comment: But i am curious where he got `equal` function in Files class ? It has [isSameFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSameFile%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path%29)
function which compares the PATH.

Comment: Hey, Sage do you just compare the path by putting the whole file name as a String starting from the C drive?

Comment: To be clear, are you using the `java.nio.file.Files` class referenced by Sage above, or the `com.google.common.io.Files` class?

Comment: @Roddy com.google.common.io.Files, because I wanted to use their HashBiMap method.

Comment: What is `DecoderWheel.main`? Is it possible that it is modifying the files in a different thread?

Comment: @Dan, are you sure that the crypted and plainFile contains the same bytes ?

Comment: Yeah, @Sage because the output is the bytes contained in the two files.  I'm certain they both have 360 bytes.  I heard that it was possibly that there is possibly an endline character throwing files.equal off, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've shown us, I think that the problem is most likely to be that the two files' contents are NOT equal.

The fact that the two byte arrays (read from the files) have the same lengths does not mean that their contents (and hence the files' contents) are the same.

Add something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < f1.length; i++) {
    if (f1[i] != f2[i]) {
        System.out.println("File content mismatch at index " + i + ": " + 
                           f1[i] + " != " + f2[i]);
    }
}
```